# Making controls fit inside custom ActionBar view

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android

My application uses a split ActionBar containing a navigation spinner and several action buttons. I wanted to use the excess space at the top to add an additional spinner, here highlighted in blue:

[image: Portrait mode]

While it appears correctly in portrait (on this specific device), landscape reveals the problem:

[image: Landscape mode]

The custom view appears to become wedged between the navigation spinner and the action buttons.

Is there some what to get the action buttons to collapse into the overflow?

Comment: Can you explain how to managed to get two spinners to appear on the upper actionbar when using split action.  I have used one spinner using the navigation spinner, and then added a second custom spinner.  However, with the split bar in portrait mode the second spinner appears on the lower actionbar and not the upper one.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure; I believe it simply worked like that out of the box. I, too, placed the highlighted spinner in a custom view. Are you using stock HC+ Actionbar, or some compatibility library? Is your test device HC+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact approach I was going for is bad practice; if the action bar is split, navigation should be at the top and actions should be at the bottom. While you could argue that selecting the time span is a navigational control, it nevertheless breaks the principle of having a single navigational control at the top of the window.

I decided against using a custom view, and instead made switching between week & month a toggle via an action button as this better fits in the Android UX.

As for the precise layout problem, I believe it can be resolved using a different list row layout for both the navigation list and the time period list that doesn't permit list items to span multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Set the `android:minWidth` attribute for the second `Spinner`. I could imagine that this will push the last items into the overflow menu.
2. Use two different menu xml files for portrait and landscape. Leave the file `/res/menu/menu.xml` as it is and create a new file in `/res/menu-land/menu.xml` where you set `android:showAsAction="never"` for some of the menu items.

Comment: Specifying `minWidth` appears to have no effect. I could try looking at the hierarchyviewer to see exactly why the layout is so stubborn, but this approach seems to be a dead end. Even if I move some menu items into the overflow, it's not a portable solution because I'd have to manually punch out different rules for different `w<N>dp` configurations, and I really don't want to head down that avenue.